# openiddict identity server and finbuckle multitenant

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant, openiddict

I would like to setup an environment that uses an identityserver (using openiddict and asp.net identity) in combination with per-tenant auth from finbuckle.
The documentation has a link to a sample but this is no longer valid(https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/tree/master/samples/ASP.NET%20Core%203/PerTenantAuthenticationSample)

Can anyone provide a basic sample on how to achieve this?
Tenant-selection would be done via subdomain name.

Thanks

Comment: you can always check the history of a GIT repository to find things which are removed now. here is the commit where the code you are looking for was removed: https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/pull/632/files check the appropriate folder for the removed code.